# Unexpected warning message to my WordPress posts which group and listed out by year

Tags: loop, errors

I have my WordPress posts looped and listed out by year successfully.
However, I am unsure why I still received a warning message.

**Warning:** Undefined variable $year_check

Below are the codes that I used on my custom theme.
Can anyone please give me some guidance?

```
<?php if( have_posts() ) : ?>
    <div id="section-2023" class="blog_news-section">
        <div class="blog_news-items">
            <?php while( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                <?php $year = get_the_date( 'Y' );
                if($year !==$year_check){
                echo "<h3>" . $year . "</h3>";
                }
                $year_check = $year;
                ?>
                <article class="blog_news-item">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="blog_news-link">
                        <div class="blog_news-img"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></div>
                        <p class="blog_news-date"><?php echo get_the_date(); ?></p>
                        <p class="blog_news-name"><?php the_title(); ?></p>
                    </a>
                </article>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
        </div>
        <?php kyoob_2023_paging_nav(); ?>
    </div>
            
<?php endif; ?>
```

Thank you in advance for your kind help, and I look forward to and appreciate all the support here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is here:

```
if($year !== $year_check){
```

The first time that conditional is used in the loop - $year_check has not been defined.

The solution is to simply define it *before* this:
`<?php if( have_posts() ) : ?>`

For example:

```
<?php $year_check = 0; ?>
<?php if( have_posts() ) : ?>
```

Comment: Oh~ you have saved my day. Thanks, @shanebp

Comment: Since the answer helped you - please accept it by clicking on the checkmark next to the answer.